# taking char input in two dimensional array

Tags: c, string, scanf

i was trying to solve tic tac toe problem. i  take sample input like this (no white space) :

```
X0X
.0.
.X.
```

i declare a two dimensional array of char `char a[3][3]` i run loops to take input but it don't take input correctly

Here is what i try :

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main() {
    int i,j;
    char a[3][3];
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            scanf("%c",&a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            printf("%c",a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

all i get return was

```
X0X

.0
.
.
```

for the sample above. i solved the problem in c++ without any bugs but in c its not working. i also try the above above code in codeforce to check if i was taking input correctly with gcc c11 compiler and found same issue. How can i solve this?

Comment: Make it `scanf(" %c",&a[i][j]);` to skip the whitespaces between the characters. Note the space before `%c`.

Comment: As opposed to other conversion specifiers like `%d` or `%s`,  `%c` does not skip whitespace like newline. You do read 9 characters from stdin; 2 of them are newlines (which are also output!) One way to fix this is to simply read all whitespace between readings of actual characters, or better, integrate this (`while (scanf("%c",&a[i][j]) && isspace(a[i][j]))  /* nothing */ ;`).

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of: [scanf() leaves the newline character in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-newline-character-in-the-buffer)

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica ok thanks. scanf reads '\n' as input too. now i added an extra scanf to read the \n like this 
        'for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            scanf("%c",&a[i][j]);
        }scanf("%c",&c);'   and the output goes correct but not sure if its a smart code.

Comment: @Humanware Medium smart -- you rely on a specific, exact format: no hidden spaces, no indentation, no CR/LF on Windows. Instead, as I suggested, I'd simply ignore all whitespace; then the format of the input data does not matter at all -- it could all be in one line, for example --, but doesn't hurt either.